# Magento Coupon code with 100% free in entire whole cart

Tags: magento, cart, coupon

I need a coupon whith 100% free in entire cart, how I can create it via admin or programatically?

(Including tax)

Answer (score 2):

To make everything free... aka $0?

PROMOTIONS > SHOPPING CART PRICE RULES > ADD NEW RULE

**Rule information tab:**
Enter rule name, status active, coupon > specific coupon and enter the code you want to use

**Actions tab**
Apply Percent of product price discount
Discount amount: 100

That's it. If everything is 100% off then that's all you need. Leave everything else blank.

If the user needs to do something to qualify then put in details in **conditions** tab to qualify.
If it's for specific products only then select them in the bottom section of the Actions tab under **Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following contitions**

Though I don't know why you would build a store to sell everything for nothing?

Comment: Thanks!! is a coupon code for a newspaper reporter and she helped us a bit, so we will give you a gift =)     This rule is not working at all, because the tax is still here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 16 months late but I also had tax / discount issues so I landed on this Page while searching for a solution.

You need to change the Tax settings to apply the discount "Including Tax"

Go to 
System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings > Apply Discount On Prices: Including Tax